# Send data from javascript to PHP using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I just tried sending data from javascript to php using ajax. Here is my code in `show.html`:

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post-button").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "get_test.php",
                data: {name: "John"}
            });
        })

    });
</script>

<body>
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<button name="post" id="post_button">Test Post</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And the php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['post_button'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    print($name);
}

?>
```

I've tried to run it, but there is no changing and also no error. Nothing is happening.
Could you tell me the problem? And also I want to get data from a form in which there is a text field inside. I will put before the button. How to get the data from that text field using javascript?

Comment: remove `$(document).ready(function(){` wrapper... it's already inside a function.

Comment: You dont need a function called post() you can give an id to your input something as `id="post"` and can trigger the `$("#post").click(function(){ }` and to get the value you can use `var val= $("#text_box_id").val();`

Comment: I've removed it, Florian. Thank you

Comment: So the code will be : $("#post").click(function(){$.ajax()... }, like that Abhik?

Answer (score 2):

Use serialize function:

```
  function showValues() {
    var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
    $( "#results" ).text( str );
  }
```

Comment: How if I have the text field, so won't create text field in the js?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't wrap document.ready() event in a function as it most likely won't ever fire and nothing will happen. All you need to do is this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post-button").on("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_test.php",
            data: {name: "John"}
        });
    });
});
</script>

<body>
<button name="post" id="post-button">Test Post</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Please adjust the code according to the example, You need to adjust the HTML, too, not only the javascript. Check if your selectors really find the required element.

Comment: <button name="post" **id="button-post"** >Test Post</button> - you have swapped the words inside the ID attribute :) Use **id="post-button"** instead.

Comment: First of all make sure that your ajax call is working fine from **Network** (in chorme).

Comment: Hit F12 and refer to the Network tab and see if the call is made. Also, you can refer to this example I've made to test it out [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JKurcik/yJXRP/2/)

Comment: Is your problem solved then? Or is there still a problem? If the problem persists then there is a problem either with your PHP file or your url. Is your php file hosted locally or is it accessible from the internet? if yes, can you post the full url here so I can see the response code?

Comment: Ah, I see it now, remove if(isset($_POST['post_button'])){ condition from your PHP code. You are not sending post_button parameter to your php handler, so the condition is always false.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="somename"/>
<button name="post" onclick=post();>Test Post</button>
<div id="someid"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
function post(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_test.php",
        data: {name: $("#somename").val()},
        success:function(data){
           $("#someid").html(data);//this will be the data returned from php
          //console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what is console.log(data) use for? and, can I don't use the `success`?

Comment: I'm sorry sir, I wanna send the data to PHP. Not for show the data in html page.

Comment: its being sent already. you don't need a click inside a function because your calling it from button anyhow. i updated again check

Comment: your question is not complete by the way

Comment: Yes, please. Thanks before

Comment: what do yo mean not complete?

Comment: you said some input field in question but i don't see it in the code. updated my answer once again..

Comment: It works, Sir. Thank you. Now, I need to use this function for my project. I've tried, but it doesn't work, no data passing. When I opened the page source, the data that I edited is not changing. How can it happen? and hot to handle, Sir?

Answer (score 0):

In your **get_test.php** file

```
<?php
    parse_str($_POST['data'], $data);
    if(isset($data['name'])){
     $name = $data['name'];
     print($name);
    }
 exit;
?>
```

Please try with this code, this may helps you.

Comment: I've tried it, but still nothing happened. Any other way?

Comment: This **'data'** is from your post send from **ajax**, and **$data** is a variable name. Simple !:)

Comment: Are you sure about your **ajax** are call when the event occur..? If sure then it should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've tried to alert name from the text field, and it works.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please use a exit with existing code, and use your console or network in browser to view the output from the ajax as your code have no return handler, like success or error.